# I couldn't pub get a package from gitlab repository that contains two packages

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

### version

Pub 2.11.0-174.0.dev

### Steps to Reproduce

I forked a package published to dartpub.
[DartPub](https://pub.dev/packages/twilio_programmable_video)
[GitLab](https://gitlab.com/twilio-flutter/programmable-video)
This package contains `twilio_programmable_video` and `twilio_programmable_video_platform_interface`.
`twilio_programmable_video` depends on `twilio_programmable_video_platform_interface`  in the repository by relative path.
Tree is like this.

```
packages
    ├ packageA
        └ pubspec.yaml
    └ packageB
        └ pubspec.yaml
```

I rewrite `pubspec.yaml` as the following.

```yaml
dependency_overrides:
  twilio_programmable_video_platform_interface:
    git:
      url: ssh://git@gitlab.com/myname/programmable-video.git
      ref: master
      path: programmable_video_platform_interface
  twilio_programmable_video:
    git:
      url: ssh://git@gitlab.com/myname/programmable-video.git
      ref: master
      path: programmable_video
```

Then I tried to `flutter pub get` and failed with the following error.

```
Error on line 17, column 11: Invalid description in the "twilio_programmable_video" pubspec on the "twilio_programmable_video_platform_interface" dependency: "../programmable_video_platform_interface" is a relative path, but this isn't a local pubspec.
   ╷
17 │     path: ../programmable_video_platform_interface
   │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
pub get failed (65;    ╵)
```

My `pubspec.yaml` is wrong?
Is there another way to write it correctly?

**Expected results:** 
`flutter pub get` finish successfully.

**Actual results:** 
An error occurred when `flutter pub get`.

Logs

```
$ flutter pub get


Error on line 17, column 11: Invalid description in the "twilio_programmable_video" pubspec on the "twilio_programmable_video_platform_interface" dependency: "../programmable_video_platform_interface" is a relative path, but this isn't a local pubspec.
   ╷
17 │     path: ../programmable_video_platform_interface
   │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
pub get failed (65;    ╵)
```

### Edit (2021-01-29 16:40:00)

I want to get a package from my gitlab repository.
I tried to get with the following specification.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  twilio_programmable_video_platform_interface:
    git:
      url: ssh://git@gitlab.com/myname/programmable-video.git
      ref: master
      path: programmable_video_platform_interface
  twilio_programmable_video:
    git:
      url: ssh://git@gitlab.com/myname/programmable-video.git
      ref: master
      path: programmable_video
```

But I got the same error.

```
Error on line 17, column 11: Invalid description in the "twilio_programmable_video" pubspec on the "twilio_programmable_video_platform_interface" dependency: "../programmable_video_platform_interface" is a relative path, but this isn't a local pubspec.
   ╷
17 │     path: ../programmable_video_platform_interface
   │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
pub get failed (65;    ╵)
```

Comment: I have same issue while I have fork record plugin. and not able to build pub with same kind of error. If you found any solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to override the package dependency in dependency overrides. If yes, you should provide the absolute/relative path of the twilio_programmable_video_platform_interface and twilio_programmable_video repos.
If you want to directly use the github repos in your project, you need to specify them under dependencies and not under dependency_overrides.

```
Snippet from pubspec.yaml:

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  built_value: ^7.1.0
  packageA:
    git:
      url: git@bitbucket.org:pkg/packageA.git
      ref: master
# Incase you want to override the above usage and instead use the repo on 
# your local machine, you can specify the path of the repo under 
# dependency_overrides.

dependency_overrides:
  analyzer: ^0.41.1
  packageA:
    path: /Users/nbm/Downloads/Projects/Flutter/pkg/packageA
```

Comment: I got the same error when write to dependencies with no dependency_overrides.